# How to get user id that create after signup in create profile page

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies

After Signup through rest api i want to get user id in create profile in order to use it when i upload images, video and other information. here is my signup api

```
Future signupUser(String name, String email, String password, String type) async {
  String url = 'myapi';
  try{
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        body: {
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'type': type

        }
    );
    var convertedDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return convertedDataJson;
  } catch(e){
    print(e);
  }
```

here is i am navigating next screen after post sign up api

```
 onPressed: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              var nameController = name.text;
                              var emailController = email.text;
                              var passwordController = password.text;
                              var userType = _user;
                             

                              var rsp = await signupUser(
                                  nameController,
                                  emailController,
                                  passwordController,
                                  userType.toString(),
                              );
                              print(rsp);
                              if (rsp['status'] == true) {
                       
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          OtpScreen(emailValue: email.text,)),
                                );
                              } else {
                                print('signup failed');
                              }
                            }
```

after sign up it create user id and i want to get that user id profile page how i can get it

here is create profile api

```
Future<ProfileModel> createProfile(
    String userId,
    String name,
    String profileImage,
    String gender,
    String age,
    String height,
    String position,
    String country,
    String countryFlag,
    String clubName,
    String clubLogo,
    String bio,
    ) async {
  String url = 'api';
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
  body: {
    'userId': userId,
    'name': name,
    'profileImage' : profileImage,
    'gender': gender,
    'age' : age,
    'height': height,
    'position': position,
    'country': country,
    'countryFlag': countryFlag,
    'clubName': clubName,
    'clubLogo': clubLogo,
    'bio': bio
  }
  );
  var createData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return createData;

}
```

i want tio get user id after sign up to use it in profile creation and image uploading kindly help

Comment: How does the object returned from signupUser looks like? Usually it will contain the created id.

Comment: @RaniSharim i am printing the response after sign up and it look like that

Comment: {status: true, message: SignUp Successfully, data: {name: abdl, type: 0, email: abdwll@gmail.com, otp: 1234, id: 105}}

Comment: as you can see it has created id and i want to get this id in create profile page

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. How to get the id or how to pass a value to another page with Flutter?

Comment: how i can pass the value id that is create after signup to another page

Comment: See if this helps: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: i want to get user id just like we get user id in firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save user id in shared preferences (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and get when ever you want

Save id

```
 Future<bool> setIsLogin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isLogin', true);
    prefs.setString('token', _systemUserModel.token);
    prefs.setString('id', _systemUserModel.id);
    prefs.setString('status', _systemUserModel.status);
    prefs.setString('email', _systemUserModel.email);
    prefs.setString('name', _systemUserModel.name);
    prefs.setString('tenantId', _systemUserModel.tenantId);

    return true;
  }
```

Read id

```
Future<bool> fetchIsLogin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isLogin = false;
    if (prefs.containsKey('isLogin')) {
      if (prefs.getBool('isLogin')!) {
        String? token = prefs.getString('token');
        String? id = prefs.getString('id');
        String? status = prefs.getString('status');
        String? email = prefs.getString('email');
        String? name = prefs.getString('email');
        String? tenantId = prefs.getString('tenantId');
        _systemUserModel =
            SystemUserModel(token!, id!, status!, email!, name!, tenantId!);
        isLogin = true;
      } else {
        isLogin = false;
      }
    } else {
      isLogin = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return isLogin;
  }
```

you can write save function in signup/logon class and read function what ever you need read id

But best practises is set this `_systemUserModel` object in `ChangeNotifierProvider` and access anywhere you want using provider package (https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: if i use getstring it will get that id that define in setstring ??

Comment: @RashidAli yes you can set and get data like this, its work kind of simple internal database for key value like token, name ,profile url etc